# Como exportar a Excel una tabla paginada en JavaScript o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatable

Espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Al exportar una tabla paginada a excel solo me exporta los datos de la página seleccionada de la tabla, todos los ejemplos que he visto y probado solo exportan la página de la tabla que se ve en el HTML dejando fuera los demás datos.

estoy trabajando con MVC NetCore, C#, JavaScript y JQuery

hasta el momento lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
function exportData() {
    var table = document.getElementById("TablaCajas");

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        column1 = row.cells[0].innerText;
        column2 = row.cells[1].innerText;
        column3 = row.cells[2].innerText;

        rows.push(
            [
                column1,
                column2,
                column3
            ]
        );

    }
    csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    rows.forEach(function (rowArray) {
        row = rowArray.join(",");
        csvContent += row + "\r\n";
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "Reporte de Cajas Operativas.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

la función se manda llamar con un input:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-editar" onclick="exportData();"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></i>&nbsp;Exportar</button>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que cargar toooodos los datos para que Javascript tenga tooodos los datos (y no sólo la página actual). Si el frontend le pide una página al backend, pues eso es lo que vas a tener disponible. SI quieres exportar tooodas las filas, tienes que hacer una petición que pida eso y que luego lo genere. ¿Lo malo? Qué pasa si son muchas filas? El navegador se come GB de memoria? Qué pasa si generas el reporte en el backend C# y sólo lo retornas como un OutputStream que tu frontend ofrecería como una descarga?

Comment: Gracias  @Alfabravo, tienes razón sobre la cantidad de filas, lo haré desde el backend

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas la extensión [buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/)? Puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Comment: @Triby no me aparecen los botones fue la primer opción que intenté y no manda ningún error en el log

Comment: @ErikcSanchezFlores, edita la pregunta para poner el código con el que estás intentando mostrar los botones y recuerda que debes incluir un [script adicional](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#Download), porque las extensiones no están integradas por defecto.